# Dynamically loading config files in python

Tags: python, config, settings

I have a Python script that calls another python module, `create_report.py`. This module has global variables that determine for example what colors should be used in the report.

Currently I have these listed just after the imports, e.g.

```
import plotly.express as px

COLOR_NEGATIVE = 'red'
COLOR_POSITIVE = 'green'

def create_bar_chart(df, y_axis, image_location):
    df['color'] = df[y_axis].apply(lambda x: COLOR_POSITIVE if x > 0 else COLOR_NEGATIVE)
    fig = px.bar(df, y=y_axis, color='color')
    fig.write_image(image_location)
```

In the other script I would then call

```
create_bar_chart(df, 'cost', 'path/to/image')
```

which would use 'red' and 'green' for color values as they are global variables.

What I'd like to do instead is to have different values for `COLOR_POSITIVE` and `COLOR_NEGATIVE`, based on config-files. These could be called e.g. via

```
import plotly.express as px

config = json.load('path/to/config')
COLOR_POSITIVE = config.get('COLOR_POSITIVE')
COLOR_NEGATIVE = config.get('COLOR_NEGATIVE')

def create_bar_chart(df, y_axis, image_location):
    df['color'] = df[y_axis].apply(lambda x: COLOR_POSITIVE if x > 0 else COLOR_NEGATIVE)
    fig = px.bar(df, y=y_axis, color='color')
    fig.write_image(image_location)
...
```

When I call `create_bar_chart` I'd like to be able to change which config file is loaded, which will determine the colors. I would create multiple configuration files for different templates, and when I call the function to create the report, it would use the correct config file to load global variables for the whole module. This way I wouldn't have to pass through the values in the functions when I call them. I know the obvious solution is to load the config file in the script that calls the module and passing those values through the functions, but it is messy and I'd like to avoid it.

Is there some way to achieve what I want?

Comment: JSON is a subset of YAML 1.2, but you cannot generally load YAML files with `json.load()`. You cannot make your `config` a global pre-loaded data structure. Either load the config in the `create_bar_chart` function, or if you use multiple configs during one program run, create some class that caches the loaded config (based on the path, which will be unique) so each config is loaded at most once.